# In Swift, how to search in a dictionary composed by an array of a struct object?

Tags: swift, uitableview, filter, uisearchbar

I have a struct:

```
struct AlimentObject {
        var id = UUID().uuidString
        var nomAliment = "Nouvel aliment"
        var poids : Float = 100
        var calories : Float = 0
}
```

and an array composed by AlimentObjet:

```
   var filteredData: [AlimentObject]!
```

i have a search bar for a table view and i don't know how to search the characters in "nomAliment"
here is the code for the searchBar:

```
extension AjoutAlimentController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredData = []
        for aliment in data {
            if aliment.nomAliment.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased) {
                filteredData.append(aliment)
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

the error says: Type '() -> String' cannot conform to 'StringProtocol'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
it 's in the line :

```
if aliment.nomAliment.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all never declare an array for filtered data as implicit unwrapped optional, declare it as non-optional empty array

```
var filteredData = [AlimentObject]()
```

Second of all – as the other answers already describe the missing parentheses – `filter` and `range(of:`) with `caseInsensitive` option is much more efficient than using a loop and *lowercasing* each item.

```
extension AjoutAlimentController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
       if searchText.isEmpty {
          filteredData.removeAll()
       } else { 
          filteredData = data.filter{$0.nomAliment.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil}
       }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing `()` after your second `lowercased`, so instead of executing the `lowercased` function and passing the returned String into `contains()`, you're passing in a function whose type is '() -> String'.

The solution, simply, is:

```
if aliment.nomAliment.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition, I suggest a functional approach to filtering

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    var filteredData = data.filter { $0.nomAliment.contains(searchText.lowercased()) }
    
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```